# Copy & Paste: Does Apple force me to use a standardized way of implementing Copy & Paste buttons/behavior?

Tags: iphone

...i mean... will they reject my app if I simply make my own COPY button at the most appropriate place in my app, for copying something to the clipboard? Or must I do that with some standardized ugly way like shaking the luxury device to death for getting some copy/paste overlay?

Comment: If you do wish to add a standard copy menu popup to a custom UI element, refer to my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534886/how-can-i-get-the-standard-iphone-copy-bubble-to-appear-on-a-uiimage/1535129#1535129

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UIPasteboard is a documented interface, so you are free to use it as you see fit.  There are no guarantees with Apple, but there is nothing I have heard about barring copy buttons.  They would probably frown on copying things to the clipboard without clear user action.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of apps that have their own "copy" buttons (see: any Twitter app). You'll be fine.